# JavaScript строки: Сравнить совпадение последних 5 символов двух строк

Tags: javascript, строки

Мне нужно проверить на совпадение окончание двух строк на >5 символов.

Если ОКОНЧАНИЯ ДВУХ строк СОВПАДАЕТ на 5 символов или больше, то вернуть true.

Если ОКОНЧАНИЯ ДВУХ строк НЕ СОВПАДАЕТ на 5 символов, то вернуть false

Если совпадение полное, то вернуть true

Например,

```
A: 4916151892822
B: 37061518928

// должно вернуть false


A: 12337065090
B: 37065090

// Последние символы совпали, должно вернуть true


A: 12348598594
B: 123

// должно вернуть false
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение.

Comment: @UModeL должно вернуть true

Comment: @UModeL Проверьте постановку вопроса, все верно, есть пример

Comment: почему в первом варианте должно вернуть false? там же окончание двух строк не совпадает. А во втором примере написано противоположное тому, что текстом указано: `// Последние символы совпали, должно вернуть true` - `Если ОКОНЧАНИЕ ДВУХ строк СОВПАДАЕТ на 5 символов или больше, то вернуть false`

Comment: Извините, исправил условие. Примеры приведены верно

Comment: гарантируется что хотя бы одна строка длиной 5 и более символов? и если нет, то какой результат, если обе строки меньшей длины: `123` и `123` например

Comment: гарантируется что хотя бы одна строка длиной 5 и более символов?
Нет, обе строки могут быть любой длины. Если 123 и 123, то должно вернуть true

Comment: почему true? совпадение же меньше 5 символов?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92090/discussion-between-drevival-and-grundy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки того, что строка заканчивается набором символов можно воспользоваться методом [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Так как нужно совпадение 5 и более символов, то достаточно проверить, что совпадают последние 5.

При этом, если длина второй строки меньше 5 и строки не совпадают нужно возвращать `false`, так как в этом случае совпадение точно меньше 5 символов.

Для получения последних 5 символов строки можно воспользоваться методом [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) с отрицательным параметром, в котором указывается количество символов с конца

В коде это может выглядеть так:

```js
function check(str1, str2) {
  if (str1 == str2) return true;
  if (str2.length < 5) return false;
  return str1.endsWith(str2.slice(-5))
}
console.log(check('4916151892822', '37061518928')) // должно вернуть false
console.log(check('12337065090', '37065090')) // Последние символы совпали, должно вернуть true
console.log(check('12348598594', '123')) // должно вернуть false
console.log(check('123', '123')) // должно вернуть true
```

Comment: Про `endsWith` только сейчас узнал. "Век живи, век учись". Пошёл разбираться.

Comment: @Grundy Есть проблема, при этой проверке  if (str2.length < 5) return false;
данный номер не отображается в принципе(не будет отрендерен на странице). Как сделать, что если длина второй строки меньше 5, то не проверять на совпадения, но номер должен быть отрендерен

Comment: @drevival, данная функции никак на влияет на вывод.